Examples of reduction of algebraic stacks
Given an algebraic stack $\mathcal X$, its reduction is the unique closed reduced substack $\mathcal X_{red}\subset \mathcal X$ such that the topological spaces associated to $\mathcal X$ and $\mathcal X_{red}$ are the same.
What are some good, non-trivial, non-scheme examples of how reduction affects an algebraic stack?
